# Fitting multiple piecewise linear regression model (with hinges)

Tags: r, multiple-regression, python, linear-model, piecewise-linear

I am trying to fit a multiple piecewise linear regression model, where I coerce the model to have the exact terms I want.

For example, let's say I want to fit the exact model below, with predictors $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, to response $y$:

$$y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3\text{max}(0, x_3 - c_3)$$

I am solving for the following parameters:

- $b_0$ : intercept
- $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ : coefficients of linear terms
- $c_3$ : cut value for hinge

(I am trying to fit many different multiple piecewise linear models, where sometimes there are more than one hinge terms; the model above is just an example)

I am using Python to code, and have tried two solutions: (1) the R library **`earth`**, which is a library that can fit models with multivariate adaptive regression splines (MARS) and (2) **`scipy.optimize`**'s **`curve_fit`** function.

I thought that **`earth`** would be the ticket; however, no matter what arguments I use for the model, the solver always discards at least one term from the fitted model. The reason (I think) is that **`earth`** always excludes linearly dependent variables, which I would like to keep. As far as I can tell, there is no way for me to coerce **`earth`** to use the exact terms I have defined.

I then tried **`scipy.optimize`**'s **`curve_fit`** function. I had to use a workaround to solve for  an arbitrary number of parameters (I used a wrapper). However, I never got it to work correctly (often reaching a maximum number of iterations for some linear models) and it was much, much slower than **`earth`**.

My questions are therefore two-fold :

1. Has anyone been able to fully coerce **`earth`** to use all terms, and only the terms, defined by the user?
2. Can anyone recommend another method (with Python or R implementation) that will fit my needs?

Comment: Why do you want to keep linearly dependent variables? The optimization problem is not well-defined if you keep them in, so it's no surprise that the solvers are trying to drop them for you. If $x_2=x_1$, then there is no well-defined solution to $y=b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2$.

Comment: There is some multicollinearity in the $x$ data, but the variables are never fully colinear. When I tried a simple multiple linear regression on the entire dataset (*i.e.,* keeping all independent variables) the resulting coefficients were much more accurate than with MARS. If there is a way to use some regularization technique (similar to Ridge regression) to deal with the multicollinearity, without fully excluding variables, then that would be ideal.