# Non-linear model where the prediction is computationally fast

Tags: python, model-selection, nonlinear-regression, splines

I am looking for a fast model that can fit several predictors $X$ to a non-linear response $y$.

To show examples of the non-linearity of the response, I have generated the plots below by sampling different values of only a single predictor at a time (*e.g.*, occDens or THeatDay). These are rather extreme cases of non-linearity; in most of the observations, the response is quite linear.

[image]
[image]

The reason I need a computationally fast model is that I use the fitted coefficients of the model to predict a *true* response through stochastic gradient descent, where each prediction call is built from simple mathematical operations (*i.e.*, an algebraic prediction). The prediction calls need to be as quick as possible in the context of my overall method.

I have tried the following non-linear models with varying degrees of problems:

1. **Polynomial regression**: does not predict the true response very well, probably due Runge's phenomenon on the edges of the data.
2. **Multivariate adaptive regression splines**: the only up-to-date API I could find is the R package `earth`, which I implemented in my Python code using `rpy2`; however, there is no way to coerce `earth` to use exactly the predictors defined by the user. `earth` will always discard at least one of my predictors, likely resulting in overfitting. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606864/fitting-multiple-piecewise-linear-regression-model-with-hinges).
3. **Natural cubic splines**: choosing the number of knots is problematic as I would like to keep the number of knots low (for quick prediction) but then underfitting can occur as their quantity is not optimized; furthermore, overfitting can occur as there is no smoothing penalty.
4. **B-splines**: complete or quasi-complete separation occurred in one or more of my predictors and the response, making the fits fail.
5. **P-splines**: to address the separation error, I tried penalizing the B-splines through *P-splines*, but the recursive nature of the B-spline bases makes the prediction too costly.

One model I would like to try is a penalized natural cubic spline with truncated power bases; however, I can't find a Python package that achieves this. I could try R's `mgcv` (see [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec.html)), again with the R-to-Python bridge `rpy2`, but first I would like to probe the community before getting lost in another rabbit hole.

Comment: Have you considered using Support Vector Regression? You may want to consider variants that enforce sparsity so you can maintain good control over the prediction time. You could also consider at training time selecting the best kernel from several different options enabling you to handle differing types of non-linearity.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @MotiNK. I've been looking into SVR and would like to know how to make an algebraic prediction. In other words, how can I use the fitted coefficients of the SVR model to write a one-line algebraic equation for the prediction?

Comment: The choice of number of knots in a natural cubic spline is very important but the actual knot locations are not that important.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @FrankHarrell. I've rectified my fundamental misunderstanding in the post.

Comment: tree based methods are your next thing to try

Comment: Tree-based methods work poorly on smooth relationships and require 10x larger sample sizes.

Comment: depends what model we have at each leaf, @FrankHarrell.

Comment: To some extent but the basic problem of instability / non-replicability and extreme overfitting pertain.  This is reflected in poor calibration curves.